# How to start an Azure VM automatically?

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-vm

I have an Azure Windows VM configed with Auto-shutdown for the sake of costing saving. It works fine that every night it shuts down the machine as scheduled.
But everyday I needs to go to Azure potal to starts it manually.
Is there a way to start the Azure VM automatically on a scheduled time? Thanks.

Comment: just a couple of alternatives: [runbook + webhook](https://4c74356b41.com/post5771) and full blown [start\stop different types of resources solution](https://4c74356b41.com/post5781)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible solutions to this problem is to use `Azure Automation`.

Detailed instructions on how to start/stop VM on a pre-defined schedule is described in details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management#scenarios.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. Thanks.